# can boolean value auto update itself if it was generated based on some logic?

Tags: java

I have declared an int x as:

```
int x = 1;
```

Lets say I declare a boolean like this

```
boolean myBool = x<2;
```

Now I change the value of x to 5. If I call the boolean again,

```
x=5;
System.out.println(myBool);
```

will it change the value to false now?
If not, how can I achieve this?

Comment: No.............

Comment: In what way are you "calling" this Boolean?

Comment: *If I call the boolean again* you don't *call* a variable, you call a method/function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no magic in Java, and variables do not magically change state. To have the boolean change state, you must code it to do so, probably best by using a `public boolean isMyBool()` method that returns a calculated property value and not use a field.

```
private int x = 0;
// boolean myBool = x < 2; // nope -- get rid of

public boolean isMyBool() {
    return x < 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the existing answer, you're looking for a `boolean`-valued function. In Java, this is known as a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

You can define the following `IntPredicate`:

```
IntPredicate myPredicate = x -> x < 2;
```

Which will produce the following output for different values of the `int` argument passed to it:

```
myPredicate.test(1); // True
myPredicate.test(5); // False
```